# save current git master branch and reset afterwards to initial commit

Tags: git

I need some help using git.

I made this mistake to do all the work in the master branch.
Due to some issues with that I want to do the following:

1. Save the current state of the master branch in another branch (e.g. the not yet existing branch backup).
2. Reset the master branch to the initial commit

I did not find any solution for this problem yet,
may someone of you help me? Best regard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to find the hash of the initial commit:

```
git log --all --grep='initial commit'
```

Then create a backup branch:

```
git checkout -b backup
```

Finally, return to the master branch and reset to the initial commit:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard <HASH>
```

Comment: thanks alot, did not know I just have to create a new branch. What does the -b means?

Comment: @DavidReichenbach yep!

Comment: @DavidReichenbach : The `-b` tells checkout to create a new branch.  The alternative, since you don't actually want to switch to the new branch anyway, is to use the `git branch` command instead of `git checkout -b`

Answer (score 0):

Create the `backup` branch.

```
git checkout master
git branch backup
```

If you want to keep one or more of the original commits on `master`, then you can just use `reset` to move the `master` branch to an earlier commit.  You need a name for the target commit.  This could be the commit ID.  Or if you know that it's, say, 5 commits before the commit at the current tip of the `master` branch, you could say `master~5`.  If the name were `T` you would say

```
git reset --hard T
```

If you don't want `master` to keep any of the existing commits, then instead you can do this:

```
git checkout --detach
git branch -D master
git checkout --orphan master
```

This will revert `master` to the state of an "unborn" branch, and your next commit will start a new history.  Don't forget that your work tree and index may still contain state from the `backup` branch, so make sure you get the index looking how you want it before committing.